# Get table data with vertical limit mysql

Tags: mysql

i need a help in get data using vertical limit with mysql query

this is my example table

```
 -----------------
| id | pid | text |
 -----------------
|  1 |   1 | abc  |
|  2 |   2 | def  |
|  3 |   3 | ghi  |
|  4 |   1 | jkl  |
|  5 |   2 | mno  |
|  6 |   4 | pqr  |
|  8 |   2 |  vw  |
|  9 |   1 | xyz  |
| 10 |   3 | stu  |
| 11 |   5 | xyz  |
| 12 |   6 | stu  |
 -----------------
```

how can i get data with limit 2 data in every pid in one query

for example table the result that i want to get is like below

```
 -----------------
| id | pid | text |
 -----------------
|  1 |   1 | abc  |
|  4 |   1 | jkl  |
|  2 |   2 | def  |
|  5 |   2 | mno  |
|  3 |   3 | ghi  |
| 10 |   3 | stu  |
|  6 |   4 | pqr  |
| 11 |   5 | xyz  |
| 12 |   6 | stu  |
 -----------------
```

can i do that??
i try explore to found the query but not found

thanks

Comment: Are you asking us how to order a result set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this.  One way uses a subquery:

```
select e.*
from example e
where 2 >= (select count(*)
            from example e2
            where e2.pid = e.pid and e2.id <= e.id
           );
```

Explanation:  the subquery is a correlated subquery.  It is counting the number of rows for each `id` that are less than a given rows `id` for the same `pid`.  That is, it is calculating the rank of the row.  The `2 >=` is just a way of getting the first two values.

Comment: When I first looked at your answer I thought you had missunderstood OP but then I looked at it again and that's a very nice solution. (y)

Comment: @Sasse could you help me to understand it? because I still same as your 'first looked' :-)  let say that I have 5 rows with id=7 and pid = 11,12,13,14,15 so `WHERE` condition is true or false?

Comment: Perhaps optimize this a tiny bit by replacing `e2.id <= e.id` with `e2.id < e.id` and `2 >=` with `2 >`. And of course, don't forget the multi-column index on (pid, id).

Comment: @MarcusAdams so in the case I asked `WHERE` will return what? false or true?

Comment: @Alex, you won't have 5 rows with id=7. Each row has a unique id.

Comment: oh, so if id are unique... then `WHERE` will return true for 11 and 12 and false for the rest? that is an idea?

Comment: @Alex I left you an "answer" to your question. An answer where I'm trying to explain why Gordons solution works.

Comment: @Sasse  thank you! I already got it. it is ok. I just think it is not very good solution from the performance perspective. But I got the logic here. That is fine! Thank you again. It is really surpirsed solution that works :-)

Comment: @GordonLinoff : Thank you this work for me,and thank for sasse explaination, that make me more understand about Gordon answer.. this is nice solution

Answer (score 1):

I cannot write so many characters in a comment to Gordon Linoff's answer so I'll write it here.

I'll try to explain why Gordon Linoff's solution works, and a little how it works.

I think of Alex question like "If I have one table with suppliers and one table with contacts and each contact belongs to a supplier. So a supplier can have many contacts but each contact can only belong to one supplier. I want a query that returns the contacts but a limit to two contacts per supplier. So we may list zero contacts for one supplier but two contact for another supplier, but never more than two."

Here below is **Gordon Linoff**s solution:

```
select e.*
from example e
where 2 >= (select count(*)
            from example e2
            where e2.pid = e.pid and e2.id <= e.id
           );
```

If we skip the whole "where"-clause at first, then we would return every contact. Now we need to check everyone of those contacts to make sure we only get a maximum of two from each supplier.

No to the where-clause. What we need to do is make sure to only select two with the same pid (supplier id). So, for every contact to check we check how many other contacts that exists that belongs to the same supplier (have the same pid) and that has a lower or equal id (contact id) as the contact that we are currently checking. And that's it.

Because if we have three contacts (say id 1, 4, 9) containing to the same supplier (pid = 22), we count the number of contacts that have the same pid (that would mean the contacts with id 1, 4 and 9 since all three have 22 as pid). Then we also check so that contact have a lower or same id and then returning the count. So when id 1 is being checked the count would be 1 since only himself have the same pid and lower or same id, then when id 4 is checked we inner "select"-statement return 2 because both id 1 and id 4 have the same pid and id lower than or equal to 4. And the where-clause in the outer select-statement reads "2 >= 2". But for the contact with id 9 all three are returned, since all have same pid and lower or equal id to 9. And "2 >= 3" will be false so contact with id 9 will not be returned.

I would believe this might be the wrong way to leave a big comment but I think some other people might be intrested in why Gordons solution works.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @num := 0, @pid:= '';

SELECT t.id, t.pid, t.text 
      @num := if(@pid = t.pid, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
      @pid := t.pid AS dummy
FROM (
   SELECT * from table_name
   ORDER BY pid, id
) as t
GROUP BY t.id,t.pid, t.text
HAVING row_number <= 2
ORDER BY t.id, t.pid;
```